# Dynamic content in body copy based on url parameter

Tags: presentation, personalization

A newbie question please:

I have a URL: www.example.com/?location=London

I want to change a part of the title, headline and body text from the default value (UK) to the supplied value (say London).

So the title of the page becomes "Cheap computers in London". If no parameter is supplied, the title will be "Cheap computers in UK".

However, Sitecore caches the HTML and hence, the content of the page is not changing when we change the parameter.

I know this can be done through JS but we need to change things server side due to some requirement.

Please advise.

Answer (score 6):

Sitecore allows you to set up caching options. Your cache could be different depending on device, parameters, query string, etc. You are also able to extend caching options (if you need).

For your case: you should turn on "VaryByQueryString" caching option on your renderings on page. Having this checkbox turned on you will have different cache depending on query string.
[image]